# Warning Errors on R studio when running trying to compute Akaike Information Criterion

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am new to Rstudio and Stack and am trying to calculate the AIC for my model with 8 variables (One dummy) but only 10 observations (Not sure if this is the issue).
The code I have run so far is:

```
library("MASS")

energy_data <- read.table('energy.txt', header = T)
full <- lm(y~., data = energy_data)
```

Following this, I get the warning

Warning messages:

```
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

I have looked at other forum threads but I am not sure if they apply in my case.

I have also tried to run this as a CSV file but in this case I get the error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ ., data = Energy, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for 'GSP') where GSP is x1

Again this has been asked before but I am unsure how to address in my case.[txt data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QYcR.png)
[CSV data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OcU2.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apologies, I have mistakenly switched around the txt and csv images.

Comment: Looking at your text data, the commas in the y column could be causing the issue.  Because y has commas, R is likely reading that in as a factor variable (hence the 'factor response' warnings).

Comment: It would be helpful for you to make the data [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), since people can't run your code on a picture of a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `,` in the `y` column, which causes it to be a factor.  You can fix it by removing the `,` using `gsub`, but in order to do that you have to change it to character first.  Once you remove the `,`, you'll need to change it to numeric.

```
library(MASS)

energy_data <- read.table(text="x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  y
361 79.7    2.983013699 1.683972603 4.35    2573.2  2048    0   77,465.59
369 86.9    2.814684932 1.701424658 4.7 2599    2094.5  0   76,705.04
375 100 2.780956284 2.006202186 3.7 2634.2  2141    0.5 72,704.99
384 119.3   3.594931507 1.448   2.75    2669.4  2266    1   70,061.93
392 123.5   3.354246575 1.522657534 2.5 2704.6  2391    0.5 69,587.52
402 114.5   3.17438562  1.653780822 2.1 2739.8  2418    0   70,138.85
410 109.3   3.691912568 1.346284153 1.75    2775    2445    0   70,405.99
418 120.8   3.725232877 1.818520548 1.5 2859.7  2586    0   70,879.50
421 136.6   3.681369863 1.79890411  1.5 2944.4  2726    0   70,436.26
431 135.2   3.960821918 1.959369863 1.2 3029.1  2867    0   70,161.83", header=T, sep="\t")

energy_data$y <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",as.character(energy_data$y)))
full <- lm(y~., data = energy_data)
```

You can also solve it by editing the file you read in to remove `,`.

```
energy_data <- read.table(text="x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  y
361 79.7    2.983013699 1.683972603 4.35    2573.2  2048    0   77465.59
369 86.9    2.814684932 1.701424658 4.7 2599    2094.5  0   76705.04
375 100 2.780956284 2.006202186 3.7 2634.2  2141    0.5 72704.99
384 119.3   3.594931507 1.448   2.75    2669.4  2266    1   70061.93
392 123.5   3.354246575 1.522657534 2.5 2704.6  2391    0.5 69587.52
402 114.5   3.17438562  1.653780822 2.1 2739.8  2418    0   70138.85
410 109.3   3.691912568 1.346284153 1.75    2775    2445    0   70405.99
418 120.8   3.725232877 1.818520548 1.5 2859.7  2586    0   70879.50
421 136.6   3.681369863 1.79890411  1.5 2944.4  2726    0   70436.26
431 135.2   3.960821918 1.959369863 1.2 3029.1  2867    0   70161.83", header=T, sep="\t")

full <- lm(y~., data = energy_data)
```